# Is it indeed possible to manage roles and member accounts using MS Graph?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I've been tasked to look into using MS Graph to manage Azure AD (aka Entra) roles and members by code. Currently I am on C# NET6 for that.

Before I dive in too deep and promise my manager something I can't deliver I want to be sure this is actually possible, because I do not see anything immediately directory related in the [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge).

**What I think I need**

Using this [link](https://graphpermissions.merill.net/permission/Directory.ReadWrite.All) you can find the available Directory related scopes:

[image]

I think I would need the highlighted scope, so Directory.ReadWrite.All.

**What I don't see**

Using Graph Explorer I can find Groups, but I don't think that's AD groups, likely that's teams and Office 365 related?

If my above assumption is correct it's strange that I do not see anything Directory
related.

**What I have**

I have used the Visual Studio Blazor Server template to generate that starter app, now with MS Graph and authentication enabled so that I also get this view:

[image]

(That line is the actual name)

It means I can confirm it's possible to at least get basic information from MS Graph, but not much else yet.

As mentioned I don't want to dive in yet, also because I would need privileged access and that needs to be discussed with the sys admins first.

**My questions**

1. Is it indeed possible to use MS Graph for Entra Role / Members management?
2. Is what I described above the correct first steps to take?
3. I remember reading that granting privileged access for MS Graph is still overruled by Entra itself. Is that true and does that mean what you can see / update is still limited by what you're allowed at Entra level?

Comment: Look at HomeController at following.  The Home controller is code on the MS Graph Server that runs windows commands.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/seamless-integration-guide-for-effortless-microsoft-graph-api-access/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to manage Azure Entra Id role assignments like the Global Administrator, User Administrator, Application Developer etc. roles. In that case the answer is yes this is possible.

For example, you can get [the role definitions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=roleManagement%2Fdirectory%2FroleDefinitions&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com) and [assignments](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=roleManagement%2Fdirectory%2FroleAssignments&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com).

For your C# code, take a look at the `graphClient.RoleManagement.Directory` object

```cs
// Code snippets are only available for the latest version. Current version is 5.x

// To initialize your graphClient, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?from=snippets&tabs=csharp
var result = await graphClient.RoleManagement.Directory.RoleAssignments.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "roleDefinitionId eq '62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10'";
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string []{ "principal" };
});
```

Required privilege for role assignments is `RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory`

Comment: Good to know I am looking in the right direction. I will investigate further and get back to you. I am also checking with our security department because they will want to know what I am up to, but it will help to know what I need to ask them.